How to capture Oracle WCC reject email text into a DB table
Currently, in our Oracle WCC Workflow, when a content is rejected, a rejection form comes up [see below] where a rejection reason is entered. That gets sent in an email to the submitter of the content and workflow tables metadata gets updated.
However, the reject reason itself is not being captured.
How can we capture a reject reason into a workflow SLQ table

It's not impossible, but quite close. It will take some heavy customization, far beyond what the developer documentation will tell you.
